# Seem to be stuck with this AxiosError code ERR_NETWORK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm new to coding and been stuck with this Axios Error for a while now, nothing seems to fix it.

Everything was working fine until it wasn't, can only see the home page of my react app and the port 8000 of my backend, any other page went blank. I really don't understand what's wrong as checked my code over and over and everything seems fine.

```
AxiosError
code: "ERR_NETWORK"
config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message: "Network Error"
name: "AxiosError"
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:52058:14)"
[[Prototype]]: Error
```

AuthModal.js

```
import { useState } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import {useCookies} from 'react-cookie'


const AuthModal = ({setShowModal, isSignUp}) => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(null)
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(null)
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['user'])

    let navigate = useNavigate()

    console.log(email, password, confirmPassword)

    const handleClick = () => {
        setShowModal(false)
    }

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        try {
            if (isSignUp && (password !== confirmPassword)) {
                setError('Passwords need to match!')
                return
            }

            const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:8000/${isSignUp ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, { email, password })

            setCookie('AuthToken', response.data.token)
            setCookie('UserId', response.data.userId)

            const success = response.status === 201
            if (success && isSignUp) navigate ('/onboarding')
            if (success && !isSignUp) navigate ('/dashboard')

            window.location.reload()

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

    }

    return (
      <div className="auth-modal">
        <div className="close-icon" onClick={handleClick}>ⓧ</div>
        
        <h2>{isSignUp ? 'CREATE ACCOUNT' : 'LOG IN'}</h2>
        <p>By clicking Log In, you agree to our terms. Learn how we process your data in our Privacy Policy and Cookie Policy. </p>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                type='email'
                id='email'
                name='email'
                placeholder="Email"
                required={true}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                />
            <input 
                type='password'
                id='password'
                name='password'
                placeholder="Password"
                required={true}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            {isSignUp && <input 
                type='password'
                id='password-check'
                name='password-check'
                placeholder="Confirm password"
                required={true}
                onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            />}
            <input className="secondary-button" type='submit'/>
                <p>{error}</p>
            </form>
            <hr/>
            <h2>GET THE APP</h2>
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default AuthModal
```

Comment: What is the error number in the browser?

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74502482/axioserror-message-network-error-name-axioserror-code-err-network-c)

Comment: Try using Axios 0.27, since the latest Axios version is broken, just remove your current axios and install axios using npm install axios@0.27.0

Comment: @Harrison there's no error number just the error I posted and this one xhr.js:247          POST http://localhost:8000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  nothing happens to the browser window apart from not taking me to the next page as it did before

Comment: @VinXi thank you very much that removed the error, but I'm having the same issue with the blank pages and the home page not redirecting me. Any ideas?

Comment: check if you are receiving a response by console logging it

Comment: "Connection refused" means the port is not open. Double check if you are running the server on port 8000. What is the backend server doing?

Comment: @VinXi no response. I don't understand everything is working and now I have this error    WebSocketClient.js:16 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed:   and still the same issue

Comment: @Harrison backend is running on port 8000, the http://localhost:8000 works but if it's any other page like http://localhost:8000/users don't work. Same happens on front end. Also on backend the app is crashing with "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..."

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good chance that you are encountering CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error, this is a security measure your browser makes. You can read more about it but here is a brief explanation on what might be going on in this case.

1. you click on submit and the request gets sent to the server
2. the server (backend) prepares the response and send it back to your browser
3. your browser blocks the response from being visible to your front application.

How you solve this, your backend server needs to specify who is eligible to get and access the response it sends. so you just need to write some code in your backend server, so please give us your backend code to see how we can help.